# RODBC can't connect in shiny-- odbcValidChannel(channel) is not TRUE

Tags: r, database, shiny, odbc, azure-sql-database

I realize there are many similar questions up about connecting to RODBC with shiny. However, none of their solutions have worked for me.

I have connected to my SQL server locally with no problem, but the published shiny app cannot  connect.

***When running the app locally I use:***

```
myData <- reactive({

##connect to database 

myServer <- "***"
myUser <- "***"
myPassword <- "**"
myDatabase <- "lto"
myDriver <- "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server" 

connectionString <- paste0(
  "Driver=", myDriver, 
  ";Server=", myServer, 
  ";Database=", myDatabase, 
  ";Uid=", myUser, 
  ";Pwd=", myPassword)

conn <- odbcDriverConnect(connectionString)

dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(connectionString)

query='SELECT [menu_item_id]
            ,[primary_brand_id],[Q1],[Q2],[Q3]
            ,[Q4],[Q5],[Q6],[Q7],[brand],[brand_parent]
            ,[menu_item_name],[course_category],[day_part]
            ,[description],[display_name],[display_with_brand]
            ,[meal_part],[product_category],[reported]
            ,[month],[year],[year_month],[period],[respondent_id]
            ,[generation],[gender],[ethnicity],[income]
            ,[eater_archetype],[survey_type]
            FROM [dbo].[vw_menu_item_responses]
            WHERE [month]=?'

#month<-3

#store results
res <- sqlExecute(channel = dbhandle, 
                  query = query,
                  data = list(input$month),
                  fetch = TRUE,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

#close the connection
odbcClose(dbhandle)
#return results
res
})

output$table<- renderDataTable({
d<-myData()
head(d)  
})
```

***When trying to publish the app, I use:***

```
 myData <- reactive({

##connect to database 
myServer <- "***"
myUser <- "***"
myPassword <- "**"
myDatabase <- "lto"
myDriver <- "FreeTDS;TDS_Version=9.0" 

connectionString <- paste0(
  "Driver=", myDriver, 
  ";Server=", myServer, 
  ";Database=", myDatabase, 
  ";Uid=", myUser, 
  ";Pwd=", myPassword)

conn <- odbcDriverConnect(connectionString)

dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(connectionString)


#build query
#query = "SELECT * FROM [my_db].[dbo].[my_table] where [CATEGORY] = '1070'"
#query = "SELECT * FROM [my_db].[dbo].[my_table] where [CATEGORY] = ?"

query='SELECT [menu_item_id]
            ,[primary_brand_id],[Q1],[Q2],[Q3]
            ,[Q4],[Q5],[Q6],[Q7],[brand],[brand_parent]
            ,[menu_item_name],[course_category],[day_part]
            ,[description],[display_name],[display_with_brand]
            ,[meal_part],[product_category],[reported]
            ,[month],[year],[year_month],[period],[respondent_id]
            ,[generation],[gender],[ethnicity],[income]
            ,[eater_archetype],[survey_type]
            FROM [dbo].[vw_menu_item_responses]
            WHERE [month]=?'

#month<-3

#store results
res <- sqlExecute(channel = dbhandle, 
                  query = query,
                  data = list(input$month),
                  fetch = TRUE,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

#close the connection
odbcClose(dbhandle)
#return results
res
  })
```

Note I have also tried the different TDS versions (7.0,8.0). Also, the issue doesn't lie with my input$month variable cause I've tried setting it to a constant and it still doesn't work.

ANY suggestions welcome. Please help.

Also obviously my userID, password, and server are not actually asterisks, but confidential info I don't want to share :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I needed to include the Port in my connection string!!.

I changed:

";Database=", myDatabase,

to:

";Port=1433;Database=", myDatabase,

Also my final solution used TDS_Version 7.0 and I am not sure if that is part of the issue.